# KML is not created

Tags: python, gis, kml

Well as the last time, I'm still in this code, but now it runs, but just sync the paths and don't create an KML file.

To take the KML information I've been used a .txt file with coordinates, Long and Lat, but even with this, it doesn't create the KML.  Follow the code

```
# Main Librarys
import simplekml
from dirsync import sync 
import re
from pathlib import Path
import os
import stat
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import stem as stem
# Functions
def read_text_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='latin1') as file:
            content = file.read()
            return content
    except Exception as e:
        print("Erro ao ler o arquivo", file_path, ":", e)
        return None

def find_query(pattern):
    path_queries = []
    matched_paths = []
    for file in Path(r'\\C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/BD_REFERENCE.py/Cliente/Gabs/documentos').rglob('*.txt'):
        path_queries.append(file.__str__())
        path_queries = os.chmod('C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/BD_REFERENCE.py/Cliente/Gabs/documentos', stat.S_IRWXU)
    for path in path_queries:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            conds = [(i.lower() in str(path).lower()) for i in pattern]
            cond = reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, conds, True)
            if cond:
                print(path)
            try:
                with open(path, encoding="latin1") as file:
                    content = file.read()
                    conds = [(re.search(i, content, re.I)) for i in pattern]
                    if all(conds):
                        matched_paths.append(path)
                        print(path)
            except:
                print("Erro com o arquivo", path)
    return matched_paths
# Main
def main():
    pattern = [r"file\(case"]
    xml = find_query(pattern)

    desc = str
    long = float()
    lat = float()
    kml = simplekml.Kml()

    if xml is not None:
        for path in xml:
            try:
                with open(path, 'r') as file:
                    content = file.read()
                    desc = Path(path).stem
                    coords_match = re.search(r'(?i)longitude: (-?\d+\.\d+),\s*latitude: (-?\d+\.\d+)', content)
                    if coords_match:
                        long = float(coords_match.group(1))
                        lat = float(coords_match.group(2))
                        kml.newpoint(description=desc, coords=[(long, lat)])
            except Exception as e:
                print("Erro ao processar o arquivo", path, ":", e)
        kml.save('Teste.kml')
    else:
        print('Nenhum arquivo encontrado que corresponda ao padrão.')

    try:
        sync('C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/BD_REFERENCE.py/', 'C:/Users/gabri/Desktop/Teste_DB.py/', 'sync', purge=True)
        print("Diretório atualizado com sucesso!")
    except ValueError:
        print("Não foi possível encontrar a pasta Teste.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I just tried everything, take more information about directories, turn the file .txt in the search pattern, and it runs, sync the path and doesn't create that sh** of KML.

Someone can  help me please?

Comment: so is your problem creating the KML or writing it out?

Comment: Like, I want add description in the polygon of KML, to get something like mapBiomas, where I can click on the area and see the information about the owner or something like, environmental  survey, without put it manually on google earth

Comment: And I can't open it, because the google show this message: " Only single root feature within <kml> tag " Something like that, and I don't know how turn around it